# React Native - How to detect font size after a font scaling?

Tags: react-native, fonts

I need to detect what is the font size for text component after a font scaling.
Let's say that I have a Text component with font size 18px

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>My Text</Text>
```

The user has set a large font through the OS accessibility settings.
Now my text has been rendered with a larger font size (more than 18px).
I'm aware that I can use `allowFontScaling={false}` but I don't want to lose the text accessibility.
I saw that React native have an API for getting the font scale `PixelRatio.getFontScale()` but it doesn't work for iOS

> Returns the scaling factor for font sizes. This is the ratio that is
>   used to calculate the absolute font size, so any elements that heavily
>   depend on that should use this to do calculations.
>
> If a font scale is not set, this returns the device pixel ratio.
>
> Currently this is only implemented on Android and reflects the user
>   preference set in Settings > Display > Font size, on iOS it will
>   always return the default pixel ratio. @platform android

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to find the font size after scaling?

Comment: @joshkmartinez A fixed height with a border bottom is one case I've run into. The text becomes swallowed by the border bottom line

Comment: Do you want to scale your fonts when the device font size changes or you want to disable font scaling?

Answer (score 8):

[react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) provides a function, getFontScale(), which appears to work in both android and iOS.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `useWindowDimensions`

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

const MyScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
   useWindowDimensions().fontScale // you will get current scale
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio) `PixelRatio.getFontScale()` should work for both Android and iOS

Comment: As of Aug 2023, it does work on both iOS and Android : https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio#getfontscale